# Pseudocompact not countably compact Hasdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

It is easy to show that not every pseudompact space is countably compact, i. e. particular point topology on $\mathbb{R}$. 
$$
\mathcal{P}=\langle \mathbb{R},\tau=\{A\subset\mathbb{R}\mid 0\in A\}\rangle
$$

I am wondering if there exists a Hausdorff space with the same properties. I have tried proving that there does not, but got no result, so I think there exists a counterexample.

**Definition 1.**
A topological space $X$ is said to be pseudocompact iff every continuous real-valued function is bounded. By continuous real-valued I mean a countinuous function between topological spaces $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$ with standart topology.
It can be shown that every continuous function form $\mathcal{P}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is constant, hence bounded.

**Definition 2.** A topological space $X$ is said to be countably compact iff you can choose a finite subcover from any countable open cover of $X$. It is obvious, that $\mathcal{P}$ does not satisfy this definition.

Comment: Mrówka’s space $\Psi$ is an example; it’s discussed in detail [here in Dan Ma’s Topology Blog](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/). It’s not just Hausdorff: it’s Tikhonov (though not normal).